# How to import ConvLSTMCell?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, convolution

Tensorflow has implemented ConvLSTM in this address:
https://www.usetensorflow.com/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/ConvLSTMCell#apply
But I do not know how to import ConvLSTMCell, in other words what's the import command for it?

Comment: `import tensorflow as tf` and then just `tf.contrib.rnn.ConvLSTMCell`

Comment: I did but I got this error:
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.rnn' has no attribute 'ConvLSTMCell'
@Maxim

Comment: What is your tf version?

Comment: It is '1.3.0'
@Maxim

Comment: You should upgrade. I think 1.3 doesn't have it